# Mostrar información en varios tabs usando un solo $scope

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estoy tratando de mostrar información que inyecto desde un ***factory*** al ***controller***, pero solo me muestra la información en el primer tab, en los otros incluso no me muestra el ***template*** por defecto.

El código es el siguiente:

### oficinas.html

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">
<volver-menu></volver-menu>
<p class="title">Oficinas</p>
 </ion-header-bar>
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-balanced">    
    <ion-tab title="Programas" href="#/oficinas/jefaturas">
        <ion-nav-view name="jefaturas-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>   
    <ion-tab title="Facultades" href="#/oficinas/decanaturas">
        <ion-nav-view name="decanaturas-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Admon" href="#/oficinas/admon">
        <ion-nav-view name="admon-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

### jefaturas.html

```
<ion-content class="color-tabs">
    <div class="list list-borderless card color-tabs" ng-repeat="programa in oficinas.departamentos">
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-person-outline"></i> {{programa.director}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-briefcase-outline"></i> {{programa.oficina}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i> {{programa.telefono}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline"></i> {{programa.correo}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></i> Horario de atencion
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

### decanaturas.html

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="list list-borderless card color-tabs" ng-repeat="decanatura in oficinas.facultades>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-person-outline"></i> {{decanatura.director}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-briefcase-outline"></i> {{decanatura.oficina}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i> {{decanatura.telefono}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline"></i> {{decanatura.correo}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></i> Horario de atencion
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

### admon.html

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="list list-borderless card color-tabs" ng-repeat="admon in oficinas.administracion">
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-person-outline"></i> {{admon.director}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-briefcase-outline"></i> {{admon.oficina}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i> {{admon.telefono}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline"></i> {{admon.correo}}
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></i> Horario de atencion
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

### oficinas.js

```
angular.module('modulo_Oficina', ['ionic'])
    .controller('iniciarTabs', iniciarTabs)
    .factory('informacionTabs', informacionTabs);

iniciarTabs.$inject = ['$scope', 'informacionTabs'];

function iniciarTabs($scope, informacionTabs) {    
    var Departamentos, Facultades, Administracion, estado;    
    informacionTabs.salirApp();
    Departamentos = informacionTabs.infoDepartamentos();
    Facultades = informacionTabs.infoDecanaturas();
    Administracion = informacionTabs.infoAdmon();

    $scope.oficinas = {
        departamentos: Departamentos,
        facultades: Facultades,
        administracion: Administracion
    }

}

informacionTabs.$inject = ['$ionicHistory', '$ionicPlatform', '$state'];

function informacionTabs($ionicHistory, $ionicPlatform, $state) {
    return {
        obtenerVista: function() {
            var vista;
            vista = $ionicHistory.currentStateName();
            return vista;
        },
        salirApp: function() {    
            var BackButton = 0;
            var atrasMenu;

            atrasMenu = $ionicHistory.backView();    
            $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function() { 
                if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'oficinas.jefaturas' || $ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'oficinas.decanaturas' || $ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'oficinas.admon') {

                    if (atrasMenu.stateName == "menuestu") {
                        $state.go('menuestu');
                    } else {
                        $state.go('menuprof')
                    }

                }   
            });    
        },    
        infoDepartamentos: function() {    
            var programas;

            programas = [{
                director: 'Alvaro Oñate',
                oficina: 'Dep. de Ing. de Sistemas',
                telefono: 5849233,
                correo: 'alvaroonate@unicesar.edu.co'
            }, {
                director: 'Ada Almenares',
                oficina: 'Dep. de Derecho',
                telefono: 5546706,
                correo: 'derecho@unicesar.edu.co'
            }, {
                director: 'Josefina Cuello',
                oficina: 'Dep. de Sociologia',
                telefono: 5846706,
                correo: 'sociología@unicesar.edu.co'
            }, {
                director: 'Iranis Urbina',
                oficina: 'Dep. de Idiomas',
                telefono: 5850296,
                correo: 'idiomas@unicesar.edu.co'
            }, {
                director: 'Ineris Cuello',
                oficina: 'Dep. de Arte y folclor',
                telefono: 585045,
                correo: 'bellasartes@unicesar.edu.co'
            }, {
                director: 'Doris Celchar',
                oficina: 'Dep. de Enfermeria',
                telefono: 5848935,
                correo: 'enfermería@unicesar.edu.co'            
            }];

            return programas;    
        },    
        infoDecanaturas: function() {    
            var decanaturas;    
            decanaturas = [{
                director: 'Efrain Quintero',
                oficina: 'Dec. de Bellas Artes',
                telefono: 5850411,
                correo: 'efrainquintero@unicesar.edu.co'
            }, {
                director: 'Jaime Maestre',
                oficina: 'Dec. de Ciencias de la educación',
                telefono: 5849456,
                correo: 'faceeducacion@unicesar.edu.co'
            }, {
                director: 'Nancy Hernandez',
                oficina: 'Dec. de Salud',
                telefono: 5850464,
                correo: '*'
            }];    
        },    
        infoAdmon: function() {   
            var admon;    
            admon = [{
                director: 'Norberto Diaz',
                oficina: 'Cefontev',
                telefono: 3145357278,
                correo: '*'
            }, {
                director: 'Averiguar',
                oficina: 'Sala de profesores',
                telefono: 5847128,
                correo: '*'
            }];   
        }    
    };    
}
```

### rutas

```
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

    $stateProvider
        //Ingreso
     .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: "Templates/login.html",
        controller: "formulario"
     })
     .state('Loading', {
         url: '/loading',
         templateUrl: "Templates/loading.html"
     });

     //Estudiante

     .state('menuestu', {
         url: '/menuestu',
         templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/menuestu.html",
         controller: "borrarHistorial"
     })
     .state('perfilestu', {
         url: '/perfilestu',
         templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/perfilestu.html",
         controller: "mostrarPerfilEstu"
     })
     .state('horarioestu', {
         url: '/horarioestu',
         templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/horarioestu.html",
         controller: "mostrarHorarioEstu"
     })
     .state('calificaciones', {
         url: '/calificaciones',
         templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/calificaciones.html",
         controller: "mostrarNotasEstu"
     })
     .state('calendarioestu', {
         url: '/calendarioestu',
         templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/calendarioestu.html"
     })

    //Profesor

    .state('menuprof', {
        url: '/menuprof',
        templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/menuprof.html",
        controller: "borrarHistorial"
    })
    .state('perfilprof', {
        url: '/perfilprof',
        templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/perfilprof.html",
        controller: "mostrarPerfilProf"
    })
    .state('horarioprof', {
        url: '/horarioprof',
        templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/horarioprof.html",
        controller: "mostrarHorarioProf"
    })
    .state('grupos', {
        url: '/grupos',
        templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/grupos.html",
        controller: "mostrarGruposProf"
    })
    .state('calendarioprof', {
        url: '/calendarioprof',
        templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/calendarioprof.html"
    })

    .state('oficinas', {
         url: '/oficinas',
         abstract: true,
         templateUrl: "Templates/Oficinas/oficinas.html"
    })

    .state('oficinas.jefaturas', {
        url: "/jefaturas",
        views: {
            'jefaturas-tab': {
                templateUrl: "Templates/Oficinas/jefaturas.html",
                controller: "iniciarTabs"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('oficinas.decanaturas', {
        url: "/decanaturas",
        views: {
            'decanaturas-tab': {
                templateUrl: "Templates/Oficinas/decanaturas.html",
                controller: "iniciarTabs"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('oficinas.admon', {
        url: "/admon",
        views: {
            'admon-tab': {
                templateUrl: "Templates/Oficinas/admon.html",
                controller: "iniciarTabs"
            }
        }
    });
```

};

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a la pregunta la definición de los estados?

Comment: Pues @rnd estan alli en el iff que esta dentro de la funcion del factory

Comment: Lo que falta es donde defines los estados del uirouter, ahí solo veo que cambias de estado.. Estoy mal ? Es que estoy con el cel y es medio complicado. :)

Comment: @rnd ya estan las rutas agregadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que todo tengo que aclararte que por lo general es buena idea tener un controller diferente por cada tab porque ayuda a reducir la cantidad de código de cada controller pero hay casos que la informacion es la misma(ej todo llega en una sola llamada ajax y los tabs ayudan a clasificar dicha información o es una app muy sencilla que tiene mucho contenido estático, etc).

Hay dos formas de lograrlo

*Primera variante:*

Usar los [tabs de CSS](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs) en lugar de la [directiva de los tabs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/). Los resultados de usar ambos componentes son similares pero no 100% idénticos.

La propiedad `$scope.currentTab` es la encargada de controlar cual es la pestaña activa usando [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) para **ocultar** y **mostrar** la lista correspondiente.

Esta variante sólo es útil en aplicaciones pequeñas ya que tiene algunos problemas que te enumero a continuación.

- Hay que manejar muchos factores manualmente como cuál es el tab activo agregandole la clase `'active'` condicionalmente con [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).
- La url del navegador no se actualiza al cambiar de pestaña por lo que si tu página se refresca el navegador *"olvida"* cual es el tab activo.

En este demo puedes ver los resultados. Como puedes comprobar sólo uso una instancia del controller y por lo tanto un sólo `$scope`.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
  .controller('IniciarCtrl', function($scope, info, $stateParams) {
    $scope.currentTab = 'programas';
    $scope.programas = info.programas;
    $scope.decanaturas = info.decanaturas;
    $scope.admon = info.admon;
  })
  .factory('info', function() {
    return {
      programas: [{
        director: 'Alvaro Oñate',
        oficina: 'Dep. de Ing. de Sistemas',
        telefono: 5849233,
        correo: 'alvaroonate@unicesar.edu.co'
      }, {
        director: 'Ada Almenares',
        oficina: 'Dep. de Derecho',
        telefono: 5546706,
        correo: 'derecho@unicesar.edu.co'
      }, {
        director: 'Josefina Cuello',
        oficina: 'Dep. de Sociologia',
        telefono: 5846706,
        correo: 'sociología@unicesar.edu.co'
      }, {
        director: 'Iranis Urbina',
        oficina: 'Dep. de Idiomas',
        telefono: 5850296,
        correo: 'idiomas@unicesar.edu.co'
      }, {
        director: 'Ineris Cuello',
        oficina: 'Dep. de Arte y folclor',
        telefono: 585045,
        correo: 'bellasartes@unicesar.edu.co'
      }, {
        director: 'Doris Celchar',
        oficina: 'Dep. de Enfermeria',
        telefono: 5848935,
        correo: 'enfermería@unicesar.edu.co'
      }],
      decanaturas: [{
        director: 'Efrain Quintero',
        oficina: 'Dec. de Bellas Artes',
        telefono: 5850411,
        correo: 'efrainquintero@unicesar.edu.co'
      }, {
        director: 'Jaime Maestre',
        oficina: 'Dec. de Ciencias de la educación',
        telefono: 5849456,
        correo: 'faceeducacion@unicesar.edu.co'
      }, {
        director: 'Nancy Hernandez',
        oficina: 'Dec. de Salud',
        telefono: 5850464,
        correo: '*'
      }],
      admon: [{
        director: 'Norberto Diaz',
        oficina: 'Cefontev',
        telefono: 3145357278,
        correo: '*'
      }, {
        director: 'Averiguar',
        oficina: 'Sala de profesores',
        telefono: 5847128,
        correo: '*'
      }]
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="IniciarCtrl">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">
    <p class="title">Oficinas</p>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <div class="tabs tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-balanced">
    <a class="tab-item" ng-class="{'active': currentTab === 'programas'}" ng-click="currentTab = 'programas'">
      Programas
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-class="{'active': currentTab === 'decanaturas'}" ng-click="currentTab = 'decanaturas'">
      Facultades
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-class="{'active': currentTab === 'admon'}" ng-click="currentTab = 'admon'">
      Admon
    </a>
  </div>
  <ion-content class="has-tabs-top color-tabs">
    <div class="list list-borderless card color-tabs" ng-repeat="programa in programas" ng-if="currentTab === 'programas'">
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-person-outline"></i> {{programa.director}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-briefcase-outline"></i> {{programa.oficina}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i> {{programa.telefono}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline"></i> {{programa.correo}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></i> Horario de atencion
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list list-borderless card color-tabs" ng-repeat="decanatura in decanaturas" ng-if="currentTab === 'decanaturas'">
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-person-outline"></i> {{decanatura.director}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-briefcase-outline"></i> {{decanatura.oficina}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i> {{decanatura.telefono}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline"></i> {{decanatura.correo}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></i> Horario de atencion
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list list-borderless card color-tabs" ng-repeat="admon in admon" ng-if="currentTab === 'admon'">
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-person-outline"></i> {{admon.director}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-briefcase-outline"></i> {{admon.oficina}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i> {{admon.telefono}}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline"></i> {{admon.correo}}
      </div>

      <div class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-clock-outline"></i> Horario de atencion
      </div>

    </div>
  </ion-content>
</div>
```

*Segunda variante (recomendada)*

Usar **un solo estado** y modificar el tab actual pasandole un parametro en lugar de declarar varios estados con urls diferentes. La url de dicho estado podría ser algo como `/vista?tab=:nombretab` o `/vista/:nombretab`

En este demo se usa un parámetro para generar una url

http://plnkr.co/edit/aCkXLhdcPmEB043mKsfL?p=preview

y en este se usa la query logrando el mismo efecto

http://plnkr.co/edit/jGEqpfkl5M76lbCSCp17?p=preview

De nuevo en estos ejemplos se usa una sola instancia de controller y por lo tanto un solo `$scope`.

Comment: Excelente como siempre, gracias de nuevo